# What is the difference between host name and sub-domain name?

Tags: dns, domain, hostname, terminology, subdomain

We know that Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) consists of **hostname.domain.TLD**.

Is that hostname also called the subdomain name? 
What's the hostname and what's the subdomain name?

Comment: It depends on the context. They can be same but usually you use a hostname to reference that specific host while you use a subdomain in the context of web service and such. You only got one hostname but can have multiple subdomains that are handled by that host. In addition a hostname doesn't necessarily have to reflect an actual DNS entry.

Comment: What's commonly called the "hostname" is the first label of a DNS FQDN that references a specific machine.  Just chop off everything after the first dot.

Answer (score 4):

DNS allows for arbitrary nesting of labels. There is no requirement that any specific label refer to a specific node.

A "node" is a sequence of labels, where typically, each label indicates a point of delegation.

For example, `com` and `uk` are labels designating top-level domains.  Within `uk` there is a static subdomain structure where effectively the "top level" is `gov.uk`, `or.uk`, `ac.uk`, `co.uk` etc (meaning "top" as in you can't register anything in `uk` directly, though of course the `uk` administrators could decide to add new second-level labels).  Many countries have this second level, though it is by no means universal (and some countries and domains have yet more internal levels like this).

For example, `example.com` is delegated by the `com` top-level domain (also called "zone") to its owner, who can further delegate individual nodes within this domain. So the owner of `example.com` could decide that there will be a subdomain `mail.example.com` and it shall contain mail servers whose names could be `mx1.mail.example.com`, `mx2.mail.example.com`, etc. This isn't very common in practice, but a really large organization could delegate part or all of its DNS further to individual departments or separate organizations.

(A common example in real life is service providers. If you run a web or email service on `example.net` you might have `ajax.example.net`, `acme.example.net` etc and have each of these delegated to your customers Ajax Inc and Acme Corp. Another scenario is regional services -- `na.example.org` to serve North America, `eu.example.org` to serve Europe, etc.)

To finally answer your actual question, whether a node is an actual host (an actual server) or just another level in the DNS is completely up to the organization who owns it.  It's not uncommon for a node to have both roles (`mail.example.info` could be an actual mail server with an IP address, and there could still be a DNS zone containing `mx1.mail.example.info` and `mx2.mail.example.info` etc.  This is not a very compelling example, I'm afraid, but there is no technical reason you couldn't do this. I'll try to think of a better example...)

A "subdomain" is just an indication that a particular label is below the top level and contains additional nodes within.  So, "sub" as in "not top", and "domain" as in "label containing more labels".

The disconnect between the mechanics of DNS (there are "zones" with "labels" identifying "nodes") and the actual real-world semantics (there is a set of root, aka top-level domains, and domains within them which are bought and sold, and subdomains within these which typically are arbitrary subdivisions implemented by the domain owner) is by and large a feature, not a bug.  The implementation does not specify any particular policy, and can be used for things which are not currently in any policy.  We have seen this spark useful innovations and new policies multiple times.

Comment: I know at some point somebody had a mail server running on their top-level domain ... If I recall correctly it was `somebody@dk` but I haven't bothered googling this.

Comment: I guess a better question would be "why would we ever want to use a hostname as a subdomain?". I mean hostnames have nothing to do with domains. Just name your hostname "jupiter" or "shrek" and then add an entry in the DNS server that points the subdomain "mail.xxx.yyy" to that exact same host. The only reason I can think of (which is not really a bad reason too) is that "one name is better than two...". But even if that's the case, I believe changing the hostname afterwards should not invalidate the domain as there's no link (other than a "logical link") between them. Is that right? Thanks.

Comment: That seems to be a separate topic. For all DNS is concerned, `jupiter` could still be either a subdomain, a host name, or both. If it has an A record, you can connect to that IP address; and if it has an NS record, labels in its zone can be looked up.